# play 2.3.0 and Scala 2.10.4

Tags: scala, playframework

Can I use Play framework version 2.3.0 with scala 2.10.4?

I know that this version of Play has 2.11.1 by default by I have a lib with 2.10.4 support only.

I get errors like these:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-ws_2.10;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.10;2.3.0: not found
```

Comment: Have you tried this a few times? Apparently their repository was having some issues today. (And as far as I can see it should just work - you can **definitely** use 2.3.0 with Scala 2.10.4.)

Comment: Just tried again, no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently a problem with the Typesafe repository (many developers have the same [problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/UBcgmOkQ9dE)).

You can temporarily add this resolver in your Build.scala/build.sbt.

```
"Typesafe Maven Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"
```